# Replacing "-W1,-rpath=\$ORIGIN" with "-W1,-rpath,\$ORIGIN" in Scons

Tags: bash, scons, rpath

I am trying to install [Openloops](https://openloops.hepforge.org/index.html) on a Mac with Scons using their provided SConstruct file. During the installation process I get the following error:

```
ld: unknown option: -rpath=$ORIGIN
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [lib/librambo.dylib] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I already know how that error could be solved, since in Mac OS you have to replace the equal sign behind rpath with a comma. However, this command is not executed by me but by the Scons script. Does anyone know if I can tell scons to parse a comma instead of the equal sign? Alternatively, can I tell bash or zsh to alias `-rpath=` with `-rpath,` somehow?

Comment: We might wish to explore this a bit more, as normally scons detects and executes platform-specific code to avoid this kind of thing.  Sometimes the build system of a project gets constructed (unintentionally) so as to defeat this, however.

Comment: Likely this issue stems from the fact that on macOS running gcc actually runs clang.. "% gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question. Put it in an answer instead.

Comment: I am indeed using a gfortran installation within gcc installed via homebrew, as opposed to clang.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following to the SConstruct

```
RPATHPREFIX="-rpath,"
```

In this part of the file:
https://gitlab.com/openloops/OpenLoops/-/blob/master/SConstruct#L381

Answer (score 0):

Within the installation path of scons-local-3.0.x/Scons I edited the files Environment.py, Tool/gnulink.py, and Tool/gdc.py and replaced `-rpath=` with `-rpath,`, the string appears once in each of the files.